# Can I use a 18AWG wire to connect a low current (LED) light to the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, led

I bought a [LED ceiling light](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B06XVQ5W2H/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with the following specifications:

- Wattage: 15W
- Voltage: 100-240V AC
- Current: 73mA

The product doesn't come with cables, and the instructions say "use a cable that meets safety regulation".

---

**Question**

Is it safe (according to regulation) to use a [18AWG stranded wire](https://www.amazon.de/Electrical-Silicone-Flexible-Temperature-Resistance/dp/B075M4VJ8J/?th=1) with the following specifications to connect the lamp to the ceiling?

- 18AWG wire (150 strands of 0.08mm tinned copper wire)
- Nominal Voltage: 600V
- Bear Current: 7.5A

---

**Update**

According to this [table of AWG wire sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes), the ampacity of an 18AWG wire is 10A (60C), and the fusing current is 83A (10s).

And here's the [answer from the manufacturer](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/ask/questions/Tx2GPLA699RECM4/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza) (LePro UK):

[image: Yes, it is safe to use an 18 gauge stranded wire.]

---

[image: Manual]

Comment: is there place to add a fuse bulb (either here or upstream at the switch)? that would let you downsize those wires safely.

Comment: Wouldn't the lamp itself break before it reached a current much greater than 73mA?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? That sounds like an awfully fine stranded wire to be using for mains wiring...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks for the response. The [product description at amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Electrical-Silicone-Flexible-Temperature-Resistance/dp/B075M4VJ8J/?th=1) says the cable is "widely used in lighting" and "lamps", but I was worried about it being too fine stranded.

Comment: The lamp could/would break but the wires could still short out and burn red hot before your breaker tripped.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://qr.ae/pNVDaN) on quora:

"Inside the walls, solid wire is usually used for 15 and 20A circuits (14 and 12 gauge) because there is no flexing of the wiring once it is in place. (...)

Although the wiring running to your lights are probably solid, the light fixtures themselves are almost always using stranded wire. Since they are simply wire-nutted onto the distribution wires, this does not present any special issues."

Comment: The wire is blatantly Chinese.  The lamp pretends to be German sourced, but it's also cheap Chinese with the certification marks faked.   What I mean is the seller is not Amazon at all, but an anonymous third party, who is making use of the Amazon Marketplace and Amazon Fulfillment (Amazon has opened their website and warehouses for use by third parties).  One of the things we've learned around here is "don't buy mains electrical gear on Amazon" because so much of it is either blatantly uncertified junk, or counterfeit (faked cert).

Comment: -1 for obvious contempt for safe installation, noting your refusal to disclose your country, to prevent us from discussing the electrical codes in your locale, and your eager desire to "litigate"/argue with general safety/Code principles.  Code is not nonsense, and is asymptotic to safety best practices.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - [Don't be so quick to judge others](https://bit.ly/3s4PsBM). I'm a novice trying to install a light fixture, and I'm doing my research. However, I can't find a definitive answer about the minimum wire gauge to connect a lamp (which I understand is not part of the house wiring, but an appliance connected to it). All comments have been helpful, prompting even more questions -- for instance, about the use of a fuse bulb, the number of strands, etc. But I still don't know if it is okay to use a 18AWG (finely stranded) wire to connect a light to the ceiling.

Comment: I feel I correctly read your "tells" but prove me wrong. **Start by naming your country**. That, plus your tells, is why none of the usual experts are answering you.

Comment: Sorry about not naming my country before, but phrase "Where are you in this planet?" sounded a bit like a veiled criticism ("From which planet are you?") and I didn't think it was an actual question.

But now I realize it is a relevant question; I live in the Netherlands, where the voltage is 230 volts and the frequency is 50 Hz.

Comment: @Nelson First, there is a **huge** difference between "Where are you on this planet" and "From which planet are you?"  Second, please understand that everyone who responds to your question actually *wants* to help you, but there is a minimum level of information we need to do this.  Just provide the requested information and instead of looking for reasons to feel insulted, look at it from the perspective of us trying to help.

Comment: @tnknepp - I didn't feel insulted, and started my reply by saying "thanks". I just didn't realize it was a question. (Keep in mind that English is not my first language and I might have misread it). Anyway... I got an answer from the manufacturer, who said it is safe to use a 18 awg wire. I also received an answer explaining that the issue might not be the current flow, but the proper connection. So, I understand that it should safe to use a 18awg wire to connect a low current (LED) light to the ceiling, as long as it is properly connected. Does this sound right?

Comment: @Nelson Good to hear no feelings were hurt!  I appreciate the issues with second languages (I picked up German a few years ago), that's part of the reason I mentioned the difference between the two sayings.  I probably could have worded that better, but with character limits it's hard to do.

Comment: I'm curious ... and I mean this sincerely ... about why you are putting so much effort into understanding whether stranded 18ga wire is "safe".   You seem to have done some research, you plan to use Wago 221s which means you do have some good idea what you're doing, you've posted a LOT of the important details.   I don't understand why you wouldn't just use 15cm of slightly heavier solid wire?   Despite their rating, I don't trust those Wagos with very fine stranded wire.  Sometimes they let go.   What's the motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed 7 lights of an identical type.  Here are my thoughts:

First 18ga wire is adequate. !8 AWG is normally considered adequate for 10 amps in lighting circuits. You should not bury that wire under anything, as it is designed for free air use.  But for one fixture, drawing less than an Amp, it will not get warm.

Second, the connector on the light is firm, but designed for 14ga solid copper wire.  Stranded wires may not have the requisite stiffness to properly insert into the connector, and there is the risk you could have a "hair" of wire separating from the strand, which could cause a problem (short).

They do not have a provision for ground wires, and since everything is plastic except the mounting bracket, I simply tied my ground to the metal mounting bracket.

Note for anyone else, to mount these lights in a box, I found it necessary to drill an additional hole in the mounting brackets.  They appear to be designed for non-US markets, and while they will work fine, some things, such as hole spacing, are not ideal for mounting on common US boxes.

How are you planning on mounting this, and running the wire to it?

Comment: 1. I was planning to place the lamp under the box, using no more than 15cm (6") of wire, and finish with two [wago 221-412](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Connection-Clamps-221-412-Conductors-Actuating/dp/B08768VL3Z/) clamp connectors.

2. Good point! Perhaps I should crimp insulated terminals?

Comment: In the US, what I would do is to use 14ga solid copper wire to attach to the light.  If going to the box there was 18ga wire, then I would use a wire nut or a crimp to attach the 14ga solid copper wire segment.  The other end of the short segment would be inserted into the lamp's crimp terminal.  The issue is not the minimum wire gauge for safe connection for current flow, but rather the requirement for proper connection in the fixture.